# In addition to the query retrieve min() and max() of a field with local parameters (alternative to StatsComponent)

Tags: solr

When querying SOLR for results add the minimum and maximum of the field `price` to that result, in relation to the local parameter `tag=price`.

Currently, we are using `stats`:

```
`stats=true&stats.field={!ex=price}price`
```

Seeing that a good part of the query time goes into this additional information (judging from `debugQuery` info), I was looking for a different way to get that information. Several ideas came to mind but none is working for me:

(A) only return `min` and `max` from `stats`, nothing else: I don't find a way to reduce the output of `stats`. Is there a way?

(B) use `json.facet`: with the following query I get the min and max price but I can only make it work **without** local parameters:

```
json.facet={price_min:'min(price)',price_max:'max(price)'}
```

fails:

```
json.facet={price_min:'min(price)',price_max:'max(price)',domain:{}}
```

> "expected facet/stat type name, like {type:range, field:price, ...} but got null , path=/facet"

```
json.facet={price_min:'min(price)',price_max:'max(price)',excludeTags:price}
```

> "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Unknown aggregation agg_price in ('price', pos=5)"

```
json.facet={price_min:'min(price)',price_max:'max(price)',domain:{excludeTags:'price'}}
```

> "Unknown facet or stat. key=domain type=excludeTags args=price , path=/facet"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try a [query facet](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/) in your json facet, like so:

```
json.facet={
        prices: {
                type: query,
                q: "*:*",
                facet: {
                    price_min:"min(price)",
                    price_max:"max(price)"
                },
                domain: {
                    excludeTags: price
                }
                // -- works also without "domain":
                // excludeTags: price
        }
}
```

Comment: This is the alternative to the stats call. Looking at debugQuery, though, it's not any faster, at least not with my index. It would probably only be an improvement if I would move *all* of the facets to `json.facet`. Currently, I fetch everything apart from price via "traditional" facets.